# How do I add an environment variable so I can run an EXE from any folder in the Windows command line?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I went to Environment Variables in the Advanced tab of System Properties and added a new System variable like this:

```
name: msbuild35
value: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
```

but when I try to run msbuild35 I still get the 'not recognized...' message

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\` to the end of the PATH environment variable.

You will likely need to close and reopen your command line window for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Hmm, still no luck. Could it be a permissions issue? I even tried rebooting to no avail. Also just tried running CMD as admin, no dice.

Comment: are you typing `msbuild35` or `msbuild`? The program is called msbuild.exe so you should be typing `msbuild`.  You could use your msbuild35 environment variable by using: `%msbuild35%` if you really wanted.

Comment: I hope windows will detect the env variable without restarting.. :-/

Comment: How to use such Variables in Windows PowerShell 2 ? Calling %Var_Name% throws an error...

Answer (score 1):

Open the Environment Variables dialog from the Advanced tab of System Properties again and do the following.

1. Delete msbuild35 that you created earlier; it is not necessary
2. Look for the `Path` variable in both sections (user and system)
3. If there is one in the user section, please let us know since that is unusual
4. Select the `Path` variable from the System Variables section and click Edit
5. Look for `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` in the value field of the dialog (you may want to copy the contents of the field to Notepad to make it easier to examine)
6. Verify that there is a semicolon before it, and if it is not the last item, after it as well
7. Click OK, OK, OK
8. Reboot
9. Open a command prompt and type `msbuild`
10. Let us know if it still does not work

Comment: Rebooting is not necessary if updates are done through the GUI. It will be enough to open a new Command Prompt through Explorer (e.g., Start Menu).

Comment: Not necessarily. Using the GUI does indeed send the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message, but that only works with normal environments. If there are any variables that include other variables, then suddenly variables stop getting expanded and a reboot *is* required (but only for users, ie, opening an elevated command-prompt still expands).